# Compare uint32_t with a loaded char[] from file C++

Tags: c++

I have a binary file from which I load whole text in unsigned char[] and a variable const uint32_t LITTLE_ENDIAN_ID = 0x49696949;
I need to compare first four characters from loaded char[] with given uint32_t.
Is that possible somehow?

Comment: You can cast the `uint32_t` address to `unsigned char*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `buff` is your `unsigned char[]` buffer, you can do:

```
memcmp((unsigned char*)&LITTLE_ENDIAN_ID, buff, 4) == 0
```

`memcmp` is defined in `string.h`

Comment: It works. I did not think about memcmp. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

yes, it's absolutely possible, but your question is underspecified. What you want to do is to take the first 4 characters of your character array and convert them into a uint32_t; the obvious question: which character corresponds to which byte of the 32-bit int?  This is probably equivalent of asking if these bytes are stored in little-endian or big-endian order.  Though now that I see your LITTLE_ENDIAN_ID I realize that it doesn't matter - it's (oddly) the same forwards and backwards.

Anyhow, what you want is either:

```
unsigned char[] text = ...
uint32_t x = text[0] << 24 + text[1] << 16 + text[2] << 8 + text[3];
if (x == LITTLE_ENDIAN_ID)
  // do something
```

Or the same thing, but with

```
uint32_t x = text[3] << 24 + text[2] << 16 + text[1] << 8 + text[0];
```

Alternatively we could do something a little more unusual like

```
union {
  uint32_t int_value;
  unsigned char[4] characters;
} converter;

unsigned char[] text = ...
converter x;
for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
  x.characters[i] = text[i];
if (x.int_value == LITTLE_ENDIAN_ID)
  // do something
```

This is probably closer to what you want if you are actually looking to test the endianness of the current system.

Comment: "we could do something a little more unusual" ... and broken. Reading a union member that was not the one that was last set is undefined behavior (there are some exceptions, but none applies here).

Comment: wait, really?  I thought that was one of the reasons to use unions.

Comment: It's a common enough thing to do, that any compiler I know of doesn't break it, but yeah UB according to the standard - we have a question to that somewhere on SO.

Comment: well I would have suggested something like `uint32_t int_value = *((unint32_t*)&text)` but I think that's also undefined behavior, because the compiler is allowed to assume that pointers to different types can't alias.